# upload video to youtube from my android application using javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I want to upload a video to youtube from my installable android application. Is there a way to do it by javascript only without calling native android codes

Comment: Check this link 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?hl=fr#Browser_based_uploading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/claudemamo/file-attach-cordova-upload-jqm use this

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript function, confirms that the user has selected a file to upload. If the user has not selected a file, then the function displays an error message.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function checkForFile() {
   if (document.getElementById('file').value) {
  return true;
   }
    document.getElementById('errMsg').style.display = '';
    return false;
  }
 </script>

   <form action="URL?nexturl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com" method="post"
   enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkForFile();">
  <input id="file" type="file" name="file"/>
 <div id="errMsg" style="display:none;color:red">
   You need to specify a file.
 </div>
 <input type="hidden" name="token" value="TOKEN"/>
  <input type="submit" value="go" />
  </form>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but in my android application the button choose file does not allow me to choose file and always displays error.. Do I need to add any extra permissions in manifest file, so as to enable choose file button